# Prolog - 'Member Of' List

Tags: list, prolog

I have a function called `member` that is supposed to take as arguments:
1) a name 
2) a list of names.

The list of names is already defined in my program, so I want to be able to call the method with a name and the list that's already initialized in the program.

For example, my Prolog program contains...

```
namesList(mike,joe,bob,jill).

member(Element, [Element|_]):-!.
member(Element, [_|Tail]):-member(Element,Tail).
```

So, when I'm at a Prolog prompt and type in `member(mike,namesList).` Prolog should output `true`, but instead prints `false`.

Am I calling the function correctly, or can I not use an already instantiated list?

Comment: `namesList`, despite it's name, does not unify to a prolog list. You should have written `namesList([mike, joe, bob, jill]).`  and your query should look like `namesList(Names), member(mike, Names).`

Comment: Prolog lists are written in brackets (`[...]`). You can find this information in any basic Prolog tutorial or in the Prolog manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Prolog doesn't have *functions*: it has *predicates*.

Second, A non-empty prolog list is written using square brackets — `[a,b,c,d]` with the empty list denoted by the atom `[]`. Lists are actually represented by the structure `./2`, where the first argument is the first item (the head) of the list and the second argument is the remainder of the list, either another non-empty list, or the empty list itself. It's what the compiler writers like to call *syntactic sugar*. So

- `[a]` is exactly equivalent to `.(a,[])`.
- `[a,b]` is exactly equivalent to `.(a,.(b,[]))`.
- `[a,b,c]` is exactly equivalent to `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))`
- etc.

And

- `[A|B]` is exactly equivelent to `.(A,B)`.

You can see why the square brackets notation is a little easier to use.

So...you could store your names list this:

```
names_list( [mike,joe,bob,jill] ).
```

in which case, you could say:

```
?- names_list( Names ) , member(mike,Names) .
true.
```

**However**...You might find it easier if you maintained your names in a more...prolog-like manner:

```
name( mike ) .
name( joe  ) .
name( bob  ) .
name( jill ) .
```

Then...

- You can check for existence in the usual way:

  ```
  ?- N = sam , name(N) ,
  false.
  ```
- Or, you can iterate over them via backtracking:

  ```
  ?- name(N).
  N = mike ;
  N = joe ;
  N = tim ;
  N = jill.
  ```
- And, if you really need them as a list, it's easy to get them in that form:

  ```
  ?- findall(N,name(N),Ns).
  Ns = [mike, joe, tim, jill].
  ```

Finally, one should note the list of names could be extracted from your

```
names_list( mike , joe , bob , jill ).
```

but it's not exactly the most elegant thing in the world:

```
extract( Name , Arguments ) :-
  atom(Name) ,
  current_functor(Name,Arity) ,
  length(Arguments,Arity) ,
  Goal =.. [Name|Arguments] ,
  callable(Goal) ,
  call(Goal)
  .
```

Once you have that, you can say:

```
?- extract(names_list,Names) , member(mike,Name).
true.
```